# Apollo GraphQL client doesn't return cached nested types in a query

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I'm performing a query to get `PowerMeter` details in which contains another type inside called `Project`. I write the query this way:

```
query getPowerMeter($powerMeterId: ID!) {
    powerMeter: powerMeter(powerMeterId: $powerMeterId) {
        id
        name
        registry
        project {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

When I perform the query for the first time, `project` is successfully returned. The problem is that when I perform subsequent queries with the same parameters and default `fetchPolicy` (`cache-first`), `project` isn't returned anymore.

How may I solve this problem?

Also, I call `readFragment` to check how `powerMeter` is saved in the cache and the response shows that `powerMeter` has `project` saved.

```
const frag = client.readFragment({
    fragment: gql`
        fragment P on PowerMeter {
            id
            name
            registry
            project {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    `,
    id: 'PowerMeter:' + powerMeterId,
});
```

**Power Meter returned first time**

```
{
  "powerMeter":{
    "id":"7168adb4-4198-443e-ab76-db0725be2b18",
    "name":"asd123123",
    "registry":"as23",
    "project":{
      "id":"41d8e71b-d1e9-41af-af96-5b4ae9e492c1",
      "name":"ProjectName",
      "__typename":"Project"
    },
    "__typename":"PowerMeter"
  }
}
```

**Fragment after calling power meter first time**

```
{
  "id":"7168adb4-4198-443e-ab76-db0725be2b18",
  "name":"asd123123",
  "registry":"as23",
  "project":{
    "id":"41d8e71b-d1e9-41af-af96-5b4ae9e492c1",
    "name":"ProjectName",
    "__typename":"Project"
  },
  "__typename":"PowerMeter"
}
```

**Power Meter returned second time**

```
{
  "powerMeter":{
    "id":"7168adb4-4198-443e-ab76-db0725be2b18",
    "name":"asd123123",
    "registry":"as23",
    "__typename":"PowerMeter"
  }
}
```

**Fragment after calling power meter second time**

```
{
  "id":"7168adb4-4198-443e-ab76-db0725be2b18",
  "name":"asd123123",
  "registry":"as23",
  "project":{
    "id":"41d8e71b-d1e9-41af-af96-5b4ae9e492c1",
    "name":"ProjectName",
    "__typename":"Project"
  },
  "__typename":"PowerMeter"
}
```

#### Edit 1: Fetching Query

The code below is how I'm fetching data. I'm using `useApolloClient` and not a query hook because I'm using AWS AppSync and it doesn't support query hook yet.

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const getPowerMeterQuery = gql`
    query getPowerMeter($powerMeterId: ID!) {
        powerMeter: powerMeter(powerMeterId: $powerMeterId) {
            id
            name
            registry
            project {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;

export const useGetPowerMeter = (powerMeterId?: string) => {
    const client = useApolloClient();
    const [state, setState] = useState<{
        loading: boolean;
        powerMeter?: PowerMeter;
        error?: string;
    }>({
        loading: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!powerMeterId) {
            return setState({ loading: false });
        }

        client
            .query<GetPowerMeterQueryResponse, GetPowerMeterQueryVariables>({
                query: getPowerMeterQuery,
                variables: {
                    powerMeterId,
                },
            })
            .then(({ data, errors }) => {
                if (errors) {
                    setState({ loading: false, error: errors[0].message });
                }

                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                const frag = client.readFragment({
                    fragment: gql`
                        fragment P on PowerMeter {
                            id
                            name
                            registry
                            project {
                                id
                                name
                            }
                        }
                    `,
                    id: 'PowerMeter:' + powerMeterId,
                });

                console.log(JSON.stringify(frag));

                setState({
                    loading: false,
                    powerMeter: data.powerMeter,
                });
            })
            .catch(err => setState({ loading: false, error: err.message }));
    }, [powerMeterId]);

    return state;
};
```

#### Edit 2: Fetching Policy Details

When I use `fetchPolice` equals `cache-first` or `network-only`, the error persists. When I use `no-cache`, I don't get the error.

Comment: Can you share the code where you're fetching the query? Also, do you manually update the relevant bits of the cache manually (i.e. after a mutation) anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @DanielRearden done! I've added how I'm fetching the query. No, I don't update the cache manually at this point

Comment: I know it's old, but it seems this issue still occurs with Apollo Client v3.2.3. My colleague opened an issue about that a few days ago (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9353). We noticed it because we were using client-only fields, and our local resolvers were breaking. Just letting you know in case it still interests you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have been the solution:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7050

Probably way too late, but it could help people coming to this issue in the future.

When using apollo client's InMemoryCache it seems you need to provide a list of possible types so the fragment matching can be done correctly when using the InMemoryCache.

You can do that manually when having few union types and a pretty stable API which doesn't change very often.
Or you automatically generate these types into a json file, which you can use directly in the InMemoryCache's possibleTypes config directly.

Visit [this link to the official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/#generating-possibletypes-automatically) to find out how to do it.

Cheers.